# Тире. Зависимость от смысла

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

На ринге (он) убийца.

(он) На ринге - (это) убийца.

Здесь тире ставится в зависимости от смысла?

Правильно ли я понимаю постановку знака?

Comment: На ринге убийца (человек, который способен убить). На ринге - убийца,  дома -  семьянин (требуется обязательное противопоставление, так как при наличии паузы логическим ударением выделяется "на ринге". Разный смысл задается наличием паузы/тире во втором предложении.

Answer (score 1):

На ринге - он убийца. (Он именно на ринге убийца). На ринге он - убийца. (Он на ринге - это убийца.)

Comment: На ринге он убийца( сообщаем факт).  На ринге  - убийца( здесь т.н. интонационное тире, которое ставится между членами предложения для выражения неожиданности  или для обозначения логического ударения.

Answer (score 1):

(1) "На ринге он убийца". Тире не ставится (местоимение в роли подлежащего). Но такой вариант вряд ли уместен, так как семантику предложения сложно выразить с помощью обычной интонации.

(2) "На рИнге он - убийца". Ставим авторское тире, обозначающее паузу и показывающее, что логическое ударение падает на обстоятельство. "На ринге он - это убийца" (то же оформление).

(3) Если местоимение пропущено, то предложение является неполным, но в виде самостоятельного предложения представить его сложно, да и вообще при выборе знака желательно видеть тот текст, к которому предложение непосредственно относится.

ПРИМЕРЫ. В жизни он обычный человек, на ринге - убийца (пауза в неполном предложении).
В жизни он обычный человек, на ринге он - это убийца (пауза в неполном предложении при различных вариантах).

ВЫВОД

При постановке тире в любых вариантах (при наличии  паузы) логическое ударение смещается на обстоятельство, что вносит важный оттенок в понимание смысла предложения.

Comment: София, здесь возможно интонационно-логическое тире.  
См. У Розенталя. Тире обычно не ставится, если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое — существительным в именительном падеже. Например:
Я грамотей и стихотворец. Я Пушкин просто, не Мусин. Я не богач, не царедворец, я сам большой: я мещанин (Пушкин).   
П р и м е ч а н и е. Тире в этом случае ставится, если нужно логически выделить один из главных членов предложения или если сказуемое выражено личным местоимением, например: Ты вся — воплощенный испуг, ты вся — вековая истома (Некрасов).

Comment: Я как раз подробно рассказываю о возможностях интонационно-логического тире в подобных предложениях.

Comment: Но при этом вы исключаете тире в первом предложении.
____
София, только я не понял один нюанс: а каком обстоятельстве идет речь?

Comment: На ринге (где) - обстоятельство. В первом предложении (в соответствии с его грамматикой)  тире обычно не ставится, но его лексическая составляющая заставляет нас поставить тире, чтобы правильно выразить смысл. И это тире приходится ставить во всех грамматических вариантах  этого предложения, они уже не оказывают влияния на постановку тире.

Comment: В то же время для окончательного вывода НАДО ВИДЕТЬ текст. Ставя тире, мы подразумеваем противопоставление (на ринге - в жизни), а если этого противопоставления нет? Может быть, герой - жестокий человек, которого автор считает способным на убийство. Тогда тире не ставится.

Comment: Я предложил другой вариант. См. мой первый ответ.

Comment: Серж, мне  предложение "На ринге - он убийца" кажется неправильным.  Оно плохо читается и не несет нового смысла по сравнению с предложением "На ринге он  - убийца", у которого с интонацией всё в порядке.

Comment: Дело не в читаемости, а в том, что надо подчеркнуть,что он именно на ринге убийца, т.е. жестокий боец.

Comment: Слово "он" отсутствует в предложении.Оно дано для пояснения.В этом соль. Если тире не ставить,то получится "На ринге убийца",т.е на ринге находится убийца.Но ни одному из примеров выше соответствия не будет.Получается,что мы не можем без " он " употреблять предложение?Но ведь в устной речи можно так сказать,если выделить смысл интонацией.

Comment: Например: - Этот человек опасен. - Почему? - На ринге убийца. 
Если здесь поставить тире, то какой из двух смыслов верен? "На ринге - он убийца" или "Он на ринге - это убийца". Для меня это разные смысловые оттенки, т.к. первый пример можно использовать в перечислении: "...на ринге - (он) убийца, дома - семьянин...   
Или я не так вижу смысловые и интонационные оттенки? Тогда в чем богатство русского языка? :)